# Database design - How to associate a item with multiple items from the same table?

Tags: database-design

I'm looking for a best practice solution....

I have table that holds products called products, certain products have other products (options) that need to be associated with them so that when users view a product they also receive a list of all the other products (options) associated with it.

My first instinct was to create a simple reference table. While this works, you'll see that there could potentially be a lot of redundant data.

```
**Ref table**
Product, product (option) to be associated

widget1, widget2
widget1, widget3
widget4, widget2 and so on...
```

My next attempt was to incorporate a key table.

```
**Products table**
product_id
key_id

**Key table**
key_id
product_id_fk
```

key_id would not be unique because a key should be able to reference more than one product(option).

This works a little better but it will still cause problems if all option sets are suppose to be unique. This method allows for only one set reference (group of options) to be associated with a product.

I believe one of the most efficient ways to solve this problem is to have all the unique sets of options created then reference each unique set to the product. Some help?

Comment: Are all product options dependent on one and only one product?  Can a product option be sold independently?

Comment: All product options are not dependent on one and only one product. Products can be part of a series, typically a option is designed to fit on an entire series.. but not always. Options CAN be sold independently, that is why I included them in the products table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the "redundant data" concern with the reference table?

- Is the relationship between A & B always reciprocal?  If we're talking about products and options, I would tend not to think so (i.e. it probably makes sense if you're selling a cell phone to provide a list of accessories as options, it probably doesn't make sense if someone is looking at cell phone cases to suggest that they buy a new phone).  If they are reciprocal, however, the `widget2, widget1` row would be redundant because you already captured that relationship with the `widget1, widget2` row.
- I assume when you are illustrating your reference table that you're storing the `product_id` for widget1, widget2, and widget3 in both columns where you write "widget1" rather than storing the actual product name which is presumably much longer than the `product_id`

Comment: I made the mistake to associate widget 1 with widget 1. The second column is meant to be an option. I typed too fast not realizing the implications... I corrected the example.

Comment: @payling - I updated my answer to remove the first bullet point.

Comment: The relationship is reciprocal. The product page for a "product" should show associated options. The product page for an "option" should show associated products. 

I currently store the product name as the primary key of the table because all products have unique names. When I say names, I mean model number (a combination of letters / digits) ....

Comment: @payling - If you don't have to store both the `widget1, widget2` and the `widget2, widget1` row because the relationship is reciprocal, what is the redundant data you're concerned about storing in the reference table?

Comment: For instance. Lets say I have 5 products. All 5 products each get 3 options that are the same. That means I'll have to repeat the same 3 options for all 5 products 5 times over.... I should be able to reference the 3 options as a set instead? So i would have the three options in some type of group. Then each of the 5 products would reference that group. Am I over thinking this solution...?

Comment: @payling - I would tend to think you're overcomplicating things.  Potentially, it would make sense to have a `FAMILY` (or `SERIES`) table that is a collection of products and another reference table that maps a `family_id` to a `product_option_id` since most options are designed to work with all products in a series.  That complicates your queries, however, since you have to look for both product- and family-specific options.

Comment: With large sets of like families I think that solution works best, but it adds a good amount of confusion to the queries. I was originally thinking of having a table called product_has_families that contained the product id and the family id. Then the families table that has a family id and product id. Once the families are established they could be re used several times. I'll probably opt for my original choice. Thanks for the help Justin.